# Почему не отправляется файл через telegram api?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

мой бот должен уметь отправлять файлы в чат, я собрал код для передачи файла:

```
        $document = new CURLFile('test.txt');
        $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendDocument?chat_id=$chat_id";
        echo $url;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ["document" => $document]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type:multipart/form-data"]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $out = curl_exec($ch);
        $err = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        var_dump($out);
        var_dump($err);
```

В итоге, в $out лежит false, в $err пусто! Почему страница не возвращает даже ответ об ошибке? Урл собирается верный,  если по нему перейти то открывается страница с ошибкой there is no document in the request. В чем проблема?

Comment: может путиь к файлу неправильный, указывай полный

Comment: Пропиши абсолютный путь к файлу

Comment: @Jean-Claude аналогичная ситуация, false и пустой вывод ошибок:(

Comment: мало ли что там может быть, с тг не работал, мало ли не все параметры задал в CURLFile(), пробуй CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, а не CURLOPT_POST, посмотри возвращенные заголовки CURLOPT_HEADER